# How to simulate SSL client failing handshake?

Tags: ssl

I have a bug in my app, which is triggered when the client disconnects in the middle of SSL handskahe. The only way I found to trigger it is to run 100 threads in [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org) and suddenly stop the test, resulting in some of those 100 threads ending in desired state. Is there some more deterministic way to test this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with open ssl s_client (https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html ) .

If you use a disabled cipher its the same as failled handshake . (-cipher SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA for example depends your server cipher :) ) .

Comment: That's good, but my app still behaves as expected when the handhsake fails because of unsupported cipher. I need to fail the handshake because the client disconnects in the middle of handshake.

Comment: To debug ssl handshake failure same soft but other options . If its after ssl handshake you must : - try with a https proxy (fiddler on windows) -check server logs for reset or other clue about ssl reset/fail .

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the connection settings in IE disabling the default one for your application (in the client) then watching it fail back to another one. For Example disable TLS1.2 on the client, watch it fail to TLS1.1(if both are supported by the server)

Comment: I was thinking more about some CLI utility, like `curl`, or `wget`.

Comment: You would probably not be able to do this with wget. With Curl it's pretty simple, just use curl --tlsv1 but the connection will fail so have it in 2 lines one with tlsv1 and one with sslv3- which should trigger if it can not retrieve it with the 1st method.